# rTorrent is ignoring different ratios for watch directories

Tags: rtorrent

I am trying to setup rTorrent to seed some torrents for longer than the default, if these torrents are loaded from a watch directory. The problem is that rTorrent seems to be stopping these torrents as soon as the default seeding ratio is reached.

Extracts from my .rtorrent.rc

#### Default Seeding ratio

```
ratio.min.set=200
ratio.max.set=210
ratio.upload.set=20M
```

#### Setting up view/group for torrents loaded from watch directory

```
view.add = view_group_2
view.persistent = view_group_2
group.insert = group_2, view_group_2
group.group_2.ratio.enable=
group.group_2.ratio.min.set=400
group.group_2.ratio.max.set=410
group.group_2.ratio.upload.set=20M
method.set = group.group_2.ratio.command, d.close=
```

#### Watch directory configuration

```
schedule = watch_directory_3,10,10,"load.start_verbose=/home/avggeek/torrent_downloads/import/hipvt_tracker/movies/*.torrent, view.set_visible=view_group_2, d.custom1.set=/home/avggeek/torrent_downloads/completed/movies/"
```

I then added a torrent to the watch directory

[image: Torrent file in watch directory]

But after the torrent exceeded the default minimum ratio, rTorrent "Closed" the torrent:

[image]

Thinking it to be a sequencing issue, I have the default seeding commands placed first, followed by the custom view commands and then the watch directory. However, this does not seem to make any difference. Any suggestions on what I should do?

I am running rTorrent 0.9.2/libtorrent 0.13.2 compiled from source (with Pyroscope's patches applied) on Debian/Squeeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rtcontrol --from-view started metafile=//hipvt_tracker/movies// \
    [ ratio=+4 OR completed=+5d ] --close --cron --yes
```

That would work. ;)

Comment: I assume to use this approach, I would have to disable all ratio commands in rtorrent.rc? If so, could you help me understand how to implement the default ratio in rtcontrol i.e., stop seeding between 2.0 and 2.1 for torrents not loaded via watch directories?

Comment: Depends on a few details, but generally "metafile=\!//watch//" with the ratio conditions added (i.e. similar to above command) would work. Pack all your rules into a bash script, and start that regularly via cron.